# Is is possible to hide label colors in list view in Mac OS 10.X Finder? I use labels as star ratings

Tags: macos, finder, label, rating

I have modified the first five label names in OS X Lion to be ★ through ★★★★★. This way I can easily tag photos etc. in the finder.

However, I find that Apple's rendering of the colored bars is horrendously ugly. I'd like to keep the labels (to be able to sort by label) but not see the colors.

I know it was possible to change the colors with Label X, but Unsanity has not issued an update for Lion.

I don't need to change the colors, just find a way to hide them in the finder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is **no way to hide the colors of the labels in the Finder**.

I still use the labels to rate files. It works really well but it makes directory listings pretty ugly.

If anyone comes up with a solution, I will be happy to select their answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would use comments rather then labels. This way you can put in "****" in comments and simply show then comments pane in finder. If I understand you correctly this would give you the desired effect.

To add a comment to a file select the file in Finder and go to File > Getinfo (or Command + i) then under Spotlight Comments enter your data.

Comment: I thought of that, but the advantage of labels is that they're available in the context menu and in the title bar of every window. Get Info is much much slower.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do this. To make my suggestion one step easier you could create an automator script and add it to the title bar so all you would have to do is click the icon and it would apply the rating. This would add the comment from a bash script. /usr/bin/xattr -w com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment "3 Stars" somefile.txt